# Refresh page adding a new random parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load an url with a random parameter. For example (`rnd` is a random value):

1. Load `www.website.com?rnd=2398`
2. Push F5
3. Automatically load `www.website.com?rnd=4583`
4. Goto step 3 is you push F5, but with a new `rnd` value

I tried use `onbeforeunload`, but I don't want it asks me if I prefer to stay here or to leave the page. I use this function too:

```
jQuery().ready(function () {
    var actualUrl = window.location.href;
    var aleat = Math.round(Math.random() * 100000);
    if (actualUrl.indexOf('rnd') != -1) {
        $("a[href]").attr('href', function (index, href) {
            if (href.indexOf("javascript") == -1 && href.indexOf("mailto") == -1) {
                return href + (href.indexOf('?') != -1 ? "&rnd=" + aleat : "?rnd=" + aleat);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

With this function, if I use rnd param then I add a new `rnd` param in all my href. So when I click in a href, a load the url with a new random param. My problem is...How can I actualize the url using F5/refresh?

Comment: set a cookie with your "rnd" value. And check the cookie and generate a new one. Best solution otherwise you have to work with php. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

And make something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var url = window.location.href;
    var rnd = url.split('rnd=')[1];
    var cookie = $.cookie("rnd");
    var newRnd = Math.round(Math.random() * 100000);

    $.cookie("rnd", newRnd);

    if(rnd == cookie || !cookie) {
        window.location.href = 'http://www.website.com/?rnd=' + newRnd;
    }
});
```

This is just a quick draft, i haven't test it but should be close, hope this helps you.

Comment: Havent tested your cookie, yet if you need to remove the rnd= part .. you need to change var rnd = url.split('rnd=')[1]; to var rnd = url.split('rnd=')[0];